# How can I add HTTP interceptors in Blazor WASM?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Angular, there is the HTTP [interceptor functionality](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses). How can I achieve the same in Blazor WASM?

[HTTP interceptors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6WL.png)

(order of the interceptors are important)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use delegating handlers. Create a new class extending `DelegatingHandler`:

```cs
public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // before request
        
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        
        // after request
    }
}
```

Then register it in Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...

builder.Services.AddTransient<MyDelegatingHandler>();

builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyDelegatingHandler>();
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#outgoing-request-middleware)

**From documentation:**

Multiple handlers can be registered in the order that they should execute. Each handler wraps the next handler until the final `HttpClientHandler` executes the request:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...

builder.Services.AddTransient<SampleHandler1>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<SampleHandler2>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MultipleHttpMessageHandlers")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<SampleHandler1>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<SampleHandler2>();
```

In the preceding code, `SampleHandler1` runs first, before `SampleHandler2`.

Comment: .AddHttpClient is not found here. Does this need a Using statement or something?

Comment: Yes it needs `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: Ok it is working now, but I need to add the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.http. Thx